# Prevent repeating + character using RegEx For Email

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I use RegEx to test for the following pattern in email address:

- The special character plus (+) should not be repeated consecutively.

Sample Cases:

Match:

```
Sam+Johns@gmail.com
```

Unmatch:

```
Sam++Johns@gmail.com
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: You could use [`^(?!.*\+{2,}).+$`](https://regex101.com/r/z8zlad/1)

Comment: Try `^(?!.*\+{2}).* where (?!.*\+{2})` is a negative lookahead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this RegEx:

`^[^+]*\+?[^+]+@[^+]+$`

You can use https://regex101.com to test your RegExs

In JS function:

```
function isValidEmail(email) {
  const pattern = /^[^+]*\+?[^+]+@[^+]+$/;
  return pattern.test(email);
}

console.log(isValidEmail('Sam+Johns@gmail.com'));   // true
console.log(isValidEmail('Sam++Johns@gmail.com'));  // false
```

Simpler way - You can just test for `\+{2,}` (thanks @mplungjan for your comment)

Comment: Perhaps just test for `\+{2,}`